# can window.event share variables?

Tags: javascript

```
this.reqURL = './appData/data.json';
this.req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        
this.req.open('get',this.reqURL);
this.req.responseType = 'json';
this.req.send();

this.resp = null;

this.req.onload = () => {
    this.resp = this.req.response;
}

console.log(this.resp);
```

```
null
```

I tried to make `this.resp` to be `this.req.response`
However, it keeps returns `null` which is default value of it.
I want `this.resp` to be `this.req.response`
can I?

(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: `this.resp` is set asynchronously. You are using it synchronously. `this.resp` is set after the request finishes. Put the `console.log(this.resp)` underneath `this.resp = this.req.response;` and it won't be null.

Comment: It's because `this.resp` inside your arrow function doesn't refer to the same `this` as outside of it. They're not within the same scope. You need to create a variable _outside_ of your arrow function that refers to the correct `this`. Something like `const myThis = this;`. Then inside the arrow function, do `myThis.resp = this.req.response;`

Comment: @Evert Yup! it works now